# Знак препинания.Почему запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Взято из книги.

Подскакали "Он" и двое его воинов,похожие друг на друга и на самого "Него" настолько,что понятно(,)родня.

Почему здесь ставится запятая,а не тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно предположить, что это авторский вариант.

Автор упрощает классическую конструкцию "понятно, что родня", надеясь на правильное восприятие смысла читателями.А делается это, по-видимому, для того, чтобы обозначить запятой ПЕРЕЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНУЮ ИНТОНАЦИЮ и ОТСУТСТВИЕ ПАУЗЫ, которая была бы обязательной при постановке тире на месте пропуска подчинительного союза.

Вероятно, именно такая мелодика предложения отвечает художественному вкусу автора.